# A String View Library in C

Tags: c, strings, parsing, api, unicode

I was recently working through the [PintOS](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/pintos.html) projects and became curious if there was a better way to do some string processing in C. Specifically, instead of `strtok_r`, I wanted to know if robust read-only tokenizer alternatives existed. I could not find any so I made my own and ended up creating some string searching functionality as well.

I modeled the [c-str-view](https://github.com/agl-alexglopez/c-str-view) library directly after `std::string_view` in C++, which I have found to be helpful in the past. I will include the interface I am considering below. Would this library help other C programmers as it helped me, or should I shelve it as a fun side project/exercise? For context, I don't have extensive experience with C and am open to learn based on feedback. My questions are as follows regarding the proposed API.

- What further functionality and documentation would a user expect to actually consider using this library? Should anything already present in the interface be changed or deleted? My goal is to make the first step of string handling as simple and robust as possible. Then if a user decides they need dynamic string management they can hopefully use these read-only views to make that job easier as they manage their own memory.
- The `str_view` type is treated as pass-by-value throughout most of the interface to provide flexible syntax and a more functional style if desired. Is this justifiable in C where that probably means 16 byte copies on 64-bit platforms?
- If this library is worth pursuing further, I am a little confused on how to approach Unicode. Right now the library only handles `const char *` data. Should it do more? How would you approach expanding the interface to cover Unicode as well?

Feel free to look at the code in the linked repository, but that is definitely not required for these questions (though it would of course be appreciated!). I am most curious about how viable this library is and how to best design the interface if it would be useful to others.

```c
#ifndef STR_VIEW
#define STR_VIEW

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* A str_view is a read-only view of string data in C. It is modeled after
   the C++ std::string_view. It consists of a pointer to const char data
   and a size_t field. Therefore, the exact size of this type may be platform
   dependent but it is small enough that one should prefer to use the provided
   functions when manupulating views. Try to avoid accessing struct fields.
   A str_view is a cheap, copyable type in all functions but swap. */
typedef struct
{
    const char *s;
    size_t sz;
} str_view;

/* Standard three way comparison type in C. See the comparison
   functions for how to interpret the comparison results. ERR
   is returned if bad input is provided to any comparison. */
typedef enum
{
    LES = -1,
    EQL = 0,
    GRT = 1,
    ERR,
} sv_threeway_cmp;

/*==========================  Construction  ================================*/

/* A macro provided to obtain the length of string literals. Best used with
   the macro below, but perhaps has uses on its own.

      static const str_view prefix = {.s = "test_", .sz = SVLEN("test_")};

   At runtime, prefer the provided functions for all other str_view needs. */
#define SVLEN(str) ((sizeof((str)) / sizeof((str)[0])) - sizeof((str)[0]))

/* A macro to reduce the chance for errors in repeating oneself when
   constructing an inline or const str_view. The input must be a string
   literal. For example, the above example becomes:

      static const str_view prefix = SV("test_");

   One can even use this in code when string literals are used rather than
   saved constants to avoid errors in str_view constructions.

       for (str_view cur = sv_begin_tok(ref, SV(" "));
            !sv_end_tok(ref_view, cur);
            cur = sv_next_tok(ref_view, cur, SV(" "))
       {}

   However saving the str_view in a constant may be more convenient. */
#define SV(str) ((str_view){(str), SVLEN((str))})

/* Constructs and returns a string view from a NULL TERMINATED string.
   It is undefined to construct a str_view from a non terminated string. */
str_view sv(const char *str);

/* Constructs and returns a string view from a sequence of valid n bytes
   or string length, whichever comes first. The resulting str_view may
   or may not be null terminated at the index of its size. */
str_view sv_n(const char *str, size_t n);

/* Constructs and returns a string view from a NULL TERMINATED string
   broken on the first ocurrence of delimeter if found or null
   terminator if delim cannot be found. This constructor will also
   skip the delimeter if that delimeter starts the string. This is similar
   to the tokenizing function in the iteration section. */
str_view sv_delim(const char *str, const char *delim);

/* Creates the substring from position pos for count length. The count is
   the minimum value between count and (str_view.sz - pos). If an invalid
   position is given greater than str_view length an empty view is returned
   positioned at the end of str_view. This position may or may not hold the
   null terminator. */
str_view sv_substr(str_view sv, size_t pos, size_t count);

/* A sentinel empty string. Safely dereferenced to view a null terminator.
   This may be returned from various functions when bad input is given
   such as NULL as the underlying str_view string pointer. */
const char *sv_null(void);

/* The end of a str_view guaranted to be greater than or equal to size.
   May be used for the idiomatic check for most string searching function
   return values when something is not found. If a size is returned from
   a searching function it is possible to check it against npos. */
size_t sv_npos(str_view sv);

/* Returns true if the provided str_view is empty, false otherwise.
   This is a useful function to check for str_view searches that yeild
   an empty view at the end of a str_view when an element cannot be
   found. See sv_svsv or sv_rsvsv as an example. */
bool sv_empty(str_view sv);

/* Returns the length of the str_view in O(1) time. */
size_t sv_len(str_view sv);

/* Returns the bytes of str_view including null terminator. Note that
   string views may not actually be null terminated but the position at
   str_view[str_view.sz] is interpreted as the null terminator and thus
   counts towards the byte count. */
size_t sv_bytes(str_view sv);

/* Returns the size of the null terminated string O(n) */
size_t sv_strlen(const char *str);

/* Returns the bytes of the string pointer to, null terminator included. */
size_t sv_strbytes(const char *str);

/* Swaps the contents of a and b. Becuase these are read only views
   only pointers and sizes are exchanged. */
void sv_swap(str_view *a, str_view *b);

/* Copies the max of str_sz or src_str length into a view, whichever
   ends first. This is the same as sv_n. */
str_view sv_copy(const char *src_str, size_t str_sz);

/* Fills the destination buffer with the minimum between
   destination size and source view size, null terminating
   the string. This may cut off src data if dest_sz < src.sz.
   Returns how many bytes were written to the buffer. */
size_t sv_fill(char *dest_buf, size_t dest_sz, str_view src);

/* Returns a str_view of the entirety of the underlying string, starting
   at the current view pointer position. This guarantees that the str_view
   returned ends at the null terminator of the underlying string as all
   strings used with str_views are assumed to be null terminated. It is
   undefined behavior to provide non null terminated strings to any
   str_view code. */
str_view sv_extend(str_view sv);

/*============================  Comparison  ================================*/

/* Returns the standard C threeway comparison between cmp(lhs, rhs)
   between two string views.
   lhs LES( -1  ) rhs (lhs is less than rhs)
   lhs EQL(  0  ) rhs (lhs is equal to rhs)
   lhs GRT(  1  ) rhs (lhs is greater than rhs).
   Comparison is bounded by the shorter str_view length. ERR is
   returned if bad input is provided such as a str_view with a
   NULL pointer field. */
sv_threeway_cmp sv_cmp(str_view lhs, str_view rhs);

/* Returns the standard C threeway comparison between cmp(lhs, rhs)
   between a str_view and a c-string.
   str_view LES( -1  ) rhs (str_view is less than str)
   str_view EQL(  0  ) rhs (str_view is equal to str)
   str_view GRT(  1  ) rhs (str_view is greater than str)
   Comparison is bounded by the shorter str_view length. ERR is
   returned if bad input is provided such as a str_view with a
   NULL pointer field. */
sv_threeway_cmp sv_strcmp(str_view lhs, const char *rhs);

/* Returns the standard C threeway comparison between cmp(lhs, rhs)
   between a str_view and the first n bytes (inclusive) of str
   or stops at the null terminator if that is encountered first.
   str_view LES( -1  ) rhs (str_view is less than str)
   str_view EQL(  0  ) rhs (str_view is equal to str)
   str_view GRT(  1  ) rhs (str_view is greater than str)
   Comparison is bounded by the shorter str_view length. ERR is
   returned if bad input is provided such as a str_view with a
   NULL pointer field. */
sv_threeway_cmp sv_strncmp(str_view lhs, const char *rhs, size_t n);

/* Returns the minimum between the string size vs n bytes. */
size_t sv_minlen(const char *str, size_t n);

/*============================  Iteration  ==================================*/

/* For the forward and reverse tokenization use the idiomatic for loop
   to acheive the desired tokenization.

      for (str_view tok = sv_begin_tok(src, delim);
           !sv_end_tok(src, tok),
           tok = sv_next_tok(src, tok, delim))
      {}

      for (str_view tok = sv_rbegin_tok(src, delim);
           !sv_rend_tok(src, tok),
           tok = sv_rnext_tok(src, tok, delim))
      {}

   Other patterns are possible but this is recommended for tokenization.
   The same applies to character iteration.

      for (const char *i = sv_begin(src); i != sv_end(src); i = sv_next(i))
      {}

      for (const char *i = sv_rbegin(src); i != sv_rend(src); i = sv_rnext(i))
      {}

   For character iteration, it is undefined behavior to change the str_view
   being iterated through before the loop terminates. */

/* Finds the first tokenized position in the string view given any length
   delim str_view. Skips leading delimeters in construction. If the
   str_view to be searched stores NULL than the sv_null() is returned. If
   delim stores NULL, that is interpreted as a search for the null terminating
   character or empty string and the size zero substring at the final position
   in the str_view is returned wich may or may not be the null termiator. If no
   delim is found the entire str_view is returned. */
str_view sv_begin_tok(str_view src, str_view delim);

/* Returns true if no further tokes are found and position is at the end
   position, meaning a call to sv_next_tok has yielded a size 0 str_view
   that points at the end of the src str_view which may or may not be null
   terminated. */
bool sv_end_tok(str_view src, str_view tok);

/* Advances to the next token in the remaining view seperated by the delim.
   Repeating delimter patterns will be skipped until the next token or end
   of string is found. If str_view stores NULL the sv_null() placeholder
   is returned. If delim stores NULL the end position of the str_view
   is returned which may or may not be the null terminator. The tok is
   bounded by the length of the view between two delimeters or the length
   from a delimeter to the end of src, whichever comes first. */
str_view sv_next_tok(str_view src, str_view tok, str_view delim);

/* Obtains the last token in a string in preparation for reverse tokenized
   iteration. Any delimeters that end the string are skipped, as in the
   forward version. If src is NULL sv_null is returned. If delim is null
   the entire src view is returned. Though the str_view is tokenized in
   reverse, the token view will start at the first character and be the
   length of the token found. */
str_view sv_rbegin_tok(str_view src, str_view delim);

/* Given the current str_view being iterated through and the current token
   in the iteration returns true if the ending state of a reverse tokenization
   has been reached, false otherwise. */
bool sv_rend_tok(str_view src, str_view tok);

/* Advances the token in src to the next token between two delimeters provided
   by delim. Repeating delimiters are skipped until the next token is found.
   If no further tokens can be found an empty str_view is returned with its
   pointer set to the start of the src string being iterated through. Note
   that a multicharacter delimiter may yeild different tokens in reverse
   than in the forward direction when partial matches occur and some portion
   of the delimeter is in a token. This is because the string is now being
   parsed from right to left. However, the token returned starts at the first
   character and is read from left to right between two delimeters as is
   in the forward tokenization.  */
str_view sv_rnext_tok(str_view src, str_view tok, str_view delim);

/* Returns a read only pointer to the beginning of the string view,
   the first valid character in the view. If the view stores NULL,
   the placeholder sv_null() is returned. */
const char *sv_begin(str_view sv);

/* Returns a read only pointer to the end of the string view. This
   may or may not be a null terminated character depending on the
   view. If the view stores NULL, the placeholder sv_null() is returned. */
const char *sv_end(str_view sv);

/* Advances the pointer from its previous position. If NULL is provided
   sv_null() is returned. */
const char *sv_next(const char *c);

/* Returns the reverse iterator beginning, the last character of the
   current view. If the view is null sv_null() is returned. If the
   view is sized zero with a valid pointer that pointer in the
   view is returned. */
const char *sv_rbegin(str_view sv);

/* The ending position of a reverse iteration. It is undefined
   behavior to access or use rend. It is undefined behavior to
   pass in any str_view not being iterated through as started
   with rbegin. */
const char *sv_rend(str_view sv);

/* Advances the iterator to the next character in the str_view
   being iterated through in reverse. It is undefined behavior
   to change the str_view one is iterating through during
   iteration. If the char pointer is null, sv_null() is returned. */
const char *sv_rnext(const char *c);

/* Returns the character pointer at the minimum between the indicated
   position and the end of the string view. If NULL is stored by the
   str_view then sv_null() is returned. */
const char *sv_pos(str_view sv, size_t i);

/* The characer in the string at position i with bounds checking.
   If i is greater than or equal to the size of str_view the null
   terminator character is returned. */
char sv_at(str_view sv, size_t i);

/* The character at the first position of str_view. An empty
   str_view or NULL pointer is valid and will return '\0'. */
char sv_front(str_view sv);

/* The character at the last position of str_view. An empty
   str_view or NULL pointer is valid and will return '\0'. */
char sv_back(str_view sv);

/*============================  Searching  =================================*/

/* Searches for needle in hay starting from pos. If the needle
   is larger than the hay, or position is greater than hay length,
   then hay length is returned. */
size_t sv_find(str_view hay, size_t pos, str_view needle);

/* Searches for the last occurence of needle in hay starting from pos
   from right to left. If found the starting position of the string
   is returned, the same as find. If not found hay size is returned.
   The only difference from find is the search direction. If needle
   is larger than hay, hay length is returned. If the position is
   larger than the hay, the entire hay is searched. */
size_t sv_rfind(str_view hay, size_t pos, str_view needle);

/* Returns true if the needle is found in the hay, false otherwise. */
bool sv_contains(str_view hay, str_view needle);

/* Returns a view of the needle found in hay at the first found
   position. If the needle cannot be found the empty view at the
   hay length position is returned. This may or may not be null
   terminated at that position. If needle is greater than
   hay length an empty view at the end of hay is returned. If
   hay is NULL, sv_null is returned (modeled after strstr). */
str_view sv_svsv(str_view hay, str_view needle);

/* Returns a view of the needle found in hay at the last found
   position. If the needle cannot be found the empty view at the
   hay length position is returned. This may or may not be null
   terminated at that position. If needle is greater than
   hay length an empty view at hay size is returned. If hay is
   NULL, sv_null is returned (modeled after strstr). */
str_view sv_rsvsv(str_view hay, str_view needle);

/* Returns true if a prefix shorter than or equal in length to
   the str_view is present, false otherwise. */
bool sv_starts_with(str_view sv, str_view prefix);

/* Removes the minimum between str_view length and n from the start
   of the str_view. It is safe to provide n larger than str_view
   size as that will result in a size 0 view to the end of the
   current view which may or may not be the null terminator. */
str_view sv_remove_prefix(str_view sv, size_t n);

/* Returns true if a suffix less or equal in length to str_view is
   present, false otherwise. */
bool sv_ends_with(str_view sv, str_view suffix);

/* Removes the minimum between str_view length and n from the end. It
   is safe to provide n larger than str_view and that will result in
   a size 0 view to the end of the current view which may or may not
   be the null terminator. */
str_view sv_remove_suffix(str_view sv, size_t n);

/* Finds the first position of an occurence of any character in set.
   If no occurence is found hay size is returned. An empty set (NULL)
   is valid and will return position at hay size. An empty hay
   returns 0. */
size_t sv_find_first_of(str_view hay, str_view set);

/* Finds the first position at which no characters in set can be found.
   If the string is all characters in set hay length is returned.
   An empty set (NULL) is valid and will return position 0. An empty
   hay returns 0. */
size_t sv_find_first_not_of(str_view hay, str_view set);

/* Finds the last position of any character in set in hay. If
   no position is found hay size is returned. An empty set (NULL)
   is valid and returns hay size. An empty hay returns 0. */
size_t sv_find_last_of(str_view hay, str_view set);

/* Finds the last position at which no character in set can be found.
   An empty set (NULL) is valid and will return the final character
   in the str_view. An empty hay will return 0. */
size_t sv_find_last_not_of(str_view hay, str_view set);

/*============================  Printing  ==================================*/

/* Writes all characters in str_view to specified file such as stdout. */
void sv_print(FILE *f, str_view sv);

#endif /* STR_VIEW */
```

Comment: Um, did you forget to post the code? Do you intend to only get the header reviewed?

Comment: Correct, I was just asking about API design, type declarations, and functions. I don't think I could ask someone to review all the code at this time until I have specific issues to highlight.

Comment: The `SVLEN` macro seems more complicated than it needs to be. Why not simply `#define SVLEN(str) (sizeof(str) - 1)`?

Comment: `((sizeof((str)) / sizeof((str)[0])) - sizeof((str)[0]))` only works because `str` is a `char` array, and `sizeof(char)==1`. If you were to put in a different array, size a wide char string (2 bytes per element), then you’d be computing the length of the string minus 2! It should of course be `((sizeof((str)) / sizeof((str)[0])) - 1)`, ie the length of the array minus 1 for the null terminator.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the source code for each of the functions is missing.

Comment: @pacmaninbw The implementation is about 1500 lines of code. Do you want that posted here? I feel that would be inappropriate. This is an API design question that I felt fell well within the [systems development lifecycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) mentioned on the site guidelines with valid C code in the header provided. Should I approach this differently in the future?

Comment: Where did you find SDLC in the guidelines of this website? That sounds like something that would be on the Software Engineering site. We only do one thing on this site, code review.

Comment: Yep, got that from the redirect to Software Engineering like you said and didn't realize I was reading the other guide, my bad. Definitely fair to close here as that site is the better fit for such a question, but migration might not be right because Harith's answer is really good. Up to you.

Comment: @AlexLopez I have made some changes to my answer that you'd be interested in.

Comment: @AlexLopez Edit 2: Made the `SV()` macro more robust.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Only include the header files that are required:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

It is useless to include both `stddef.h` and `stdio.h` for `size_t`. Remove `stdio.h`.

---

### The value of each subsequent enumerator is one greater than the previous enumerator:

So you can just do:

```c
typedef enum
{
    LES = -1,
    EQL,
    GRT,
    ERR,
} sv_threeway_cmp;
```

instead of:

```c
typedef enum
{
    LES = -1,
    EQL = 0,
    GRT = 1,
    ERR,
} sv_threeway_cmp;
```

They should also be prefixed with `SV_`, similar to how all the functions are prefixed with `sv_`.

---

### Functions that receive pointers should use array syntax and distinguish different cases:

The function declarations aren't as self-descriptive as they could be. C (since C99, or about 25 years) has a method for declaring a pointer parameter that must not be null. This is done by the rarely used syntax of putting the `static` keyword inside the parameter declaration:

```c
void func(char arg[static 1])
{
    ....
}
```

This says that `arg` must point to the first element of an array of at least one element, per [C 2011 [N1570] 6.7.6.3 7](https://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.7.6), which means that it can not be null.

Now I will present 3 ways this syntax can be utilized to distinguish different cases:

1. A pointer to a single object of type `char`:

```c
void func(char arg[static 1]);
```

2. A pointer to a collection of objects of known numbers of type `char`:

```c
void func(char arg[static 256]);
```

3. A pointer to a collection of objects of unknown numbers of type `char`:

```c
void func(size_t n, char arg[static n]);
```

And of course, without the array syntax:

4. A pointer to a single object of type `char` or a null pointer:

```c
void func(char *arg);
```

(The above are my notes from the book Modern C by Jens Gustedt. It is a great read, and a new C2X version has been released recently.)

Now after learning this, we can rewrite these two function declarations:

```c
/* Constructs and returns a string view from a NULL TERMINATED string.
   It is undefined to construct a str_view from a non terminated string. */
str_view sv(const char *str);

/* Constructs and returns a string view from a sequence of valid n bytes
   or string length, whichever comes first. The resulting str_view may
   or may not be null terminated at the index of its size. */
str_view sv_n(const char *str, size_t n);
```

as:

```c
/* Constructs and returns a string view from a NULL TERMINATED string.
   It is undefined to construct a str_view from a non terminated string. */
str_view sv(const char str[static 1]);

/* Constructs and returns a string view from a sequence of valid n bytes
   or string length, whichever comes first. The resulting str_view may
   or may not be null terminated at the index of its size. */
str_view sv_n(size_t n, const char str[static n]);
```

Note that you can also use [GNU C's function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), namely `__attribute((nonnull))__` and `__attribute((null_terminated_string_arg))__`. I'd also suggest looking into `pure`, `const`, `malloc`, et cetera as I see benefit in using them in your library. For instance, `sv_strbytes()`, `sv_len()`, and `sv_strlen()` are pure functions, and `sv_len()` is also a constant function.

See my code [here](https://github.com/Melkor-1/utils/blob/main/attrib.h) for some idea on how to use them portably. They are supported by GCC, Clang, and Intel's compiler. Or this short example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define ATTRIB_NONNULL(...)             __attribute__((nonnull(__VA_ARGS__)))
#else
    #define ATTRIB_NONNULL(...)             /**/
#endif

static size_t my_strlen(const char s[static 1])
{
    return strlen(s);
}

ATTRIB_NONNULL(1) static size_t my_strlen1(const char *s) 
{
    return strlen(s);
}

int main(void)
{
    return my_strlen(NULL), my_strlen1(NULL);
}
```

And the output it produced (`make null_diagnostic`):

```
null_diagnostic.c: In function ‘main’:
null_diagnostic.c:22:29: warning: argument 1 null where non-null expected [-Wnonnull]
   22 |     return my_strlen(NULL), my_strlen1(NULL);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~
null_diagnostic.c:15:33: note: in a call to function ‘my_strlen1’ declared ‘nonnull’
   15 | ATTRIB_NONNULL(1) static size_t my_strlen1(const char *s)
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
null_diagnostic.c:22:12: warning: argument 1 to ‘char[static 1]’ is null where non-null expected [-Wnonnull]
   22 |     return my_strlen(NULL), my_strlen1(NULL);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
null_diagnostic.c:10:15: note: in a call to function ‘my_strlen’
   10 | static size_t my_strlen(const char s[static 1])
      |               ^~~~~~~~~
```

See @Lundin's answer here for all the use-cases of the keyword `static`: [What does the static keyword do in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285050/285051#answer-285051)

### Do not obfuscate macro definitions:

```c
/* At runtime, prefer the provided functions for all other str_view needs. */
#define SVLEN(str) ((sizeof((str)) / sizeof((str)[0])) - sizeof((str)[0]))
```

Since `str` is supposed to be a string literal, this is simply:

```c
#define SVLEN(str) (sizeof(str) - 1)
```

### Use `"" ""` to force a macro argument to be a string literal:

Currently, `SV()` and `SVLEN()` function-like macros allow more than just string literals. If we have:

```c
#define SV(str)    (sizeof(str) - 1)

int main(void)
{
    static const char *const s = "hello";
    char word[] = "hello";
    double a = 0.0f;
    double *d = &a;
    
    printf("%zu\n", SV(NULL));
    printf("%zu\n", SV(word));
    printf("%zu\n", SV(d));
    printf("%zu\n", SV(s));
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles correctly and issues no errors or warnings, and the output is:

```
7
5
7
7
```

But that wouldn't be the case if you were to use the weird empty string literals in its expansion `"" str ""` to ensure that `SV()` is always called with a string literal (this works because consecutive string literals are concatenated):

```c
#define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)

int main(void)
{
    static const char *const s = "hello";
    char word[] = "hello";
    double a = 0.0f;
    double *d = &a;

    printf("%zu\n", SV(NULL));
    printf("%zu\n", SV(word));
    printf("%zu\n", SV(d));
    printf("%zu\n", SV(s));

    return 0;
}
```

Now if we compile this, we get:

```
macro_str.c: In function ‘main’:
macro_str.c:4:33: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                 ^~
macro_str.c:19:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SV’
   19 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(NULL));
      |                     ^~
macro_str.c:4:40: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                ~       ^~
macro_str.c:19:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SV’
   19 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(NULL));
      |                     ^~
macro_str.c:20:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘word’
   20 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(word));
      |                        ^~~~
macro_str.c:4:36: note: in definition of macro ‘SV’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                    ^~~
macro_str.c:4:32: note: to match this ‘(’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                ^
macro_str.c:20:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SV’
   20 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(word));
      |                     ^~
macro_str.c:21:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘d’
   21 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(d));
      |                        ^
macro_str.c:4:36: note: in definition of macro ‘SV’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                    ^~~
macro_str.c:4:32: note: to match this ‘(’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                ^
macro_str.c:21:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SV’
   21 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(d));
      |                     ^~
macro_str.c:22:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘s’
   22 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(s));
      |                        ^
macro_str.c:4:36: note: in definition of macro ‘SV’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                    ^~~
macro_str.c:4:32: note: to match this ‘(’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                ^
macro_str.c:22:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SV’
   22 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(s));
      |                     ^~
make: *** [<builtin>: macro_str] Error 1
```

It could be made more robust with extra expressions:

```c
#define SV(str)    ("" str "", (str)[0], sizeof(str) - 1)

// Credit: @n. m. could be an AI
```

This would also fail for:

```c
SV()
SV(/*comment*/)
SV(-)
SV("abc" - "def")
```

Note that the value of a comma operation will always be the value of the last expression.

### `str_view` should be an opaque pointer type:

The definition of `str_view` is not needed in the header file. The header should only contain a forward declaration and the corresponding source file should contain the definition.

But if for some reason the type needs to be in the header file, and it is desired that the compiler should raise a warning any time a client tries to access the internal members of the `struct`, we can use C2X's new `[[deprecated]]` attribute, which isn't solely for marking a function as obsolete. But instead of paraphrasing a whole article here, I suggest you read Jenn's article yourself: [The deprecated attribute in C23 does much more than marking obsolescence](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2024/01/06/the-deprecated-attribute-in-c23-does-much-more-than-marking-obsolescence/).

**Minor**:

In the documentation for `sv_empty()`, "yeild" should be "yield".

---

`size_t sv_strlen(const char *str);` doesn't work on `str_view`s, so why has it been defined? Is it perchance more efficient than `strlen()`. I see no reason to use this instead of the standard `strlen()`.

---

```c
/* Returns the bytes of the string pointer to, null terminator included. */
size_t sv_strbytes(const char *str);
```

To me, `sv_strbytes()` would make more sense as `sv_strsize()` or similar.
But I do not see why we have a `sv_strbytes()` function that doesn't even work on `str_view`s. `sv_strbytes(s)` is just `strlen(s) + 1`, but didn't we already define `sv_strlen()`? One is sure to get confused by 4 separate length/size functions. I'd simply elide it.

---

```c
/* Returns a view of the needle found in hay at the first found
   position. If the needle cannot be found the empty view at the
   hay length position is returned. This may or may not be null
   terminated at that position. If needle is greater than
   hay length an empty view at the end of hay is returned. If
   hay is NULL, sv_null is returned (modeled after strstr). */
str_view sv_svsv(str_view hay, str_view needle);
```

`sv_svsv()`, seriously? I am certain this can be named better. Same goes for `sv_rsvsv()`.

---

*A pure function is a function with basically no side effects. The return value is solely bases on given parameters and global memory, but cannot affect the value of any other global variable. The memory pointed to by a parameter is not considered a parameter, but global memory. strlen() is an example of a pure function. A counter-example of a non-pure function is called the strcpy() function.*

*A special case of pure functions is constant functions. A pure function that does not access global memory, but only its parameters, is called a constant function. A constant function can handle pointers as both parameters and return value only if they're never dereferenced. These requirements also recursively applies to all the functions it calls.*

Comment: Great points, thank you! As a follow up, I considered making `str_view` opaque but couldn't figure it out. I think it is valuable to pass `str_view` by copy or have easy reassignment (i.e. `str_view some_view = other_view`) and it seems I lose that capability with the forward declaration approach. Do you think the `[[deprecated]]` solution is the best here or do you have other thoughts on the value of making `str_view` seem "trivially copyable?"

Comment: @AlexLopez Your arguments for keeping the definition in the header seem valid. The `[[deprecated]]` attribute is one option, though it is not very elegant and is new. I'd suggest leaving it as it is.

Comment: Good answer, but you shouldn't have answered the question due to the missing source code.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Thank you. I was under the impression that it'd be fine to review just the header, since that's what OP wanted, but I'd keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @Harith Please bare in mind, whether the question is off topic or not isn't clear. Only one CV exists on the question.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I see now, but is this question actually off-topic?

Comment: @Harith IMO no.

Comment: _"Use `"" ""` to force a macro argument to be of type `char *`, be immutable, be nonnull, and be null-terminated"_ -- the way that this section is written doesn't make much sense to me. First, surrounding the macro argument with empty string literals does not force anything to be `char *`; this is just taking advantage of string literal token concatenation in an attempt to catch arguments which are not (identically prefixed) string literals. String literals are not `char *`, they are tokens which are converted to arrays of `char`.

Comment: String literals are not immutable; attempting to modify the storage associated with a string literal causes undefined behavior. Historically some C implementations have allowed string literals to be mutated. "Nonnull" and "null-terminated" seem to be other ways of saying that the macro argument must be a string literal.

Comment: @adabsurdum All that is correct, I was only attempting to quote Jenn. Is the wording of that section better now? If not, would you be willing to edit the answer accordingly?

Comment: Excellent review. One possible gotcha: if you pass a string to a function and call `sizeof(function_parameter)`, you get `sizeof(char*)`, thanks to the type decaying. Could be a bug attractor for `SVLEN`.

Comment: @Harith -- I like the wording better now. A couple of comments about the "type-checking" macros: you only need one empty literal, e.g., `(sizeof(str "") - 1)`. This will also catch the case `SV(-)`. I think that I would consider the _"more robust"_ version to be too-clever-by-half; the simpler macro does what you want, i.e., excludes pointer arguments. The _"more robust"_ version triggers warnings on GCC when warnings are turned up to a minimum acceptable level of at least `-Wall` due to **"left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect."**